# Monitoring Dedicated Server Performance

Tags: plesk, dedicated-hosting, windows-server-2008

I have a dedicated server running Windows Web Server 2008 and Parallel Plesk 12. Sometimes I am experiencing extreme slow performance accessing website hosted on dedicated server. When it is slow, I am also troubling accessing remote desktop.

So, is there anyway that will keep record of the server performance so that I can later on review what's going on and etc?

Comment: Does the Window Performance Monitor not help?? It may take a while to nail down what is going on, but you should be able to start a monitor and capture the results to a file to be reviewed later. This is especially useful when you can nail-down a set of criteria that appear about the same time so that you can predict times or circumstances when the problem will occur. Otherwise, you would just pick a few prime monitors and let it go till the problem occurs and then you stop the monitor and then review the file.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks a lot for your comment. But how to use Windows Performance Monitor? Do I need to run it to start tracking?

Comment: It has been over a decade since I dealt with Windows. I used to find it under Administrative Tools > Performance. It is a GUI based tool that you will need to open and set up. I would suggest just checking for the basics, CPU, memory, disk at first to know where to narrow down. From there, you can get more specific. You can capture to a file for review. You may also have to leave the GUI open- not sure if the newer versions allow monitoring in the background. Not sure if that is an option for you. I am sure the tool has become more sophisticated in the past 12+ years.

Answer (score 1):

As @closetnoc states what you are after is known as the performance monitor in Windows.

To launch it open the run dialog and type in `perfmon` and press enter.

To get an immediate and real-time view of CPU utilization click on `Performance Monitor` on the left hand console tree. The colour scheme of the graph is different (red over white), but it is the same graph as you can see under Task Manager.

To enable logging you have to create a new Data Collector set. On the navigation panel on the left, expand `Data Collector Set` and right click on `User Defined`. From the new menu click `Data Collector Set`.

[image]

Give a name to the set that you can recognize later, and choose the radio button `Create Manually`. Click next.

[image]

Under type of data choose `Create Data Log` and check the box `Performance Counter`. Click next.

[image]

Now is the time to choose the performance counters which you would like to log. Click on the `Add` button and choose one of the many avaiable counters, You can log processor utilization, processor idle time or interrupt time, memory usage, etc. In this example, we choose processor time.

[image]

Adjust the poll interval, 5 second should do. At this point you can click `Finish`.

Once the data set has been created run it. The data collector set will start recording data from the chosen performance monitor. Reports aren't available when the data set is running. After you stop it, you can see your report under the reports directory in the navigation panel.

[image]